# Inverse of a matrix (Show that A is invertible and find the inverse)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am struggling with a problem in Linear Algebra.

[Problem#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mprtV.jpg)
Here I tried presenting the product $AX$ as a multiplication of $A$ and $x$. We know that $X$ is invertible, so if we show that $\lambda X$ is the inverse of $A X$  that will mean that both $A$ and $X$ are invertible (I guess...) I tried using the following theorems:

- If $A$ is invertible => $\ AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A=I $
- If $A$ and $B$ are invertible => $\ (AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1} $

P.S.: This is my first post here on the forum.

Comment: You've got $n $ linearly independent eigenvectors, with nonzero eigenvalues. Thus, $A $ is diagonalizable. Moreover, the diagonal matrix it is similar to has nonzero entries on the diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

$A x_i = \lambda_i x_i\\
X = [x_1,x_2\cdots,x_n]$

$AX = X\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1\\&\lambda_2\\&&\lambda_3\\&&&\ddots\end{bmatrix}$

Lets call this diagonal matrix $\Lambda$

Since every $\lambda_i$ is non-zero, $\det \Lambda \ne 0$

And since $X$ is invertable. The determinant of $X$ is not $0$

$\det(AX) = \det(A)\det(X) = \det(X)\det(\Lambda)\ne 0\\
\det(A)\ne 0$

And $A$ is invertable

What is $A^{-1}$

$(AX)^{-1} = X^{-1} A^{-1} = \Lambda^{-1}X^{-1} = (X\Lambda)^{-1}\\
A^{-1} = X\Lambda^{-1}X^{-1} $

And what do you suppose $\Lambda^{-1}$ is?

Comment: Hey @Doug M, 
Thank you so much for your reply. Could you please explain the one before last line a bit further? 

So we know that A is invertible because $\ det(A)=/= 0 $ ?
And so we write $\ (AX)^{-1}=X^{-1}A^{-1} $ because it`s a theorem. Now what happens after that? How do we get to $\ Λ^{−1}X^{−1} $ ? 

Many Thanks,

Comment: $AX = X\Lambda\implies (AX)^{-1} = (X\Lambda)^{-1} \implies X^{-1}A^{-1} = \Lambda^{-1}X^{-1} \implies A^{-1} = X\Lambda^-1X^{-1}$